# Add multi-column fulltext index fails with 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a fulltext index onto an existing table in MySQL. I can successfully add a single column fulltext index on this table, however if I try and add a multicolumn index it fails. I am wanting to add a multicolumn fulltext index to enable searching across multiple columns in a SELECT query.

Schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE `emailarchive_people` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailAddress` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person` (`name`,`emailAddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100230 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The following single index creation query works:

```
ALTER TABLE
    `emailarchive_people`
ADD
    FULLTEXT INDEX `name` (`name`);
```

However the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE
    `emailarchive_people`
ADD
    FULLTEXT INDEX `personFT` (`name`,`emailAddress`);
```

...fails with the following response:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'NULL-NULL' for key 'emailarchive_people.personFT'
```

I have also tried dropping the unique `person` key before attempting to add the `personFT` index, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109242

Likely since you are using FULLTEXT INDEX that this is the case.

Comment: Oh wow, so basically it is run it until it works? That worked for me if it helps anyone.

Comment: I encountered this kind of issue on MySQL 8.0.23 with 160k records when I created a full text index with multiple column.

Comment: @hectorviov perhaps, it may be that you have so many rows it will never succeed. It seems that more rows = more chance to encounter this issue.

Comment: It seems the bug is now fixed and will be part of 8.2.0. Not sure why they are not putting it in 8.0.34.

Comment: Bug has been fixed in release 8.0.35

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can create a new table with the same definition, create a multi-column full-text search index on this empty table, then copy all the data from the existing table and switch them.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `emailarchive_people_new` LIKE `emailarchive_people`;
ALTER TABLE `emailarchive_people_new` 
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `personFT` (`name`,`emailAddress`);
INSERT INTO `emailarchive_people_new` SELECT * FROM `emailarchive_people`;
RENAME TABLE `emailarchive_people` TO `emailarchive_people_old`, 
             `emailarchive_people_new` TO `emailarchive_people`;
```

**NOTE**: It can cause some downtime and new data added during switching can be lost. Make sure you have enough disk storage for the table copy and for indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting exactly the same error when applying a multi fulltext index.

It worked with only a few data rows. With 10,000+ it fails.

Server version: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 Debian 11

```
ALTER TABLE `customer`
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `search` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `postcode`, `email`);
```

/* SQL Fehler (1062): Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'customer.key_paydate' */

The error message makes no sense as `customer.key_paydate` is not an unique key and no entry of that column is NULL

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX search_order_address ON shipping_order (pickup_address, delivery_address) WITH PARSER ngram':

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'shipping_order.search_order_address'
```

I searched and there was a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102833), [docs with fulltext optimizations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-rebuild-innodb-indexes) and [some blog entry with this bug](https://dbadojo.com/2020/06/12/error-innodb-duplicate-key-writing-word-node-to-fts-auxiliary-index-table/) (this was probably what worked for me).

So what I tried was `OPTIMIZE TABLE` (not sure if this is required but just in case)

```sql
set GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=ON;
OPTIMIZE TABLE shipping_order;
```

and just after this

```sql
ALTER TABLE shipping_order ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Next time I run this

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX search_order_address ON shipping_order (pickup_address, delivery_address) WITH PARSER ngram;
```

it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately these steps didn't work for me. Looks like I'm stuck with this problem until the MySQL folks fix the bug per answer from @notoriouspyro.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a table with 2.5 mln records and what worked for me is setting `innodb-ddl-buffer-size=64M` variable in the server conf file and restarting the server. It seems like this variable is dynamic, so you cna also change it during the runtime with

`SET GLOBAL innodb_ddl_buffer_size=67108864;`

After that I could add a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on several columns without any `NULL` value errors.