# Simple MySQL query with ORDER BY too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by

Edit:The time spent for querying a normal word is actually 1.78 seconds. The 4.5 seconds mentioned in the original post below was when querying special words like '.vnet'. (I know `REGEXP '\\b.vnet\\b'` won't find the whole word match for '.vnet'. I might use a more complex regex to fix this later, or drop the support for '.vnet' if it's too time-consuming.) Also I added solution 5 below.

---

I have the following MySQL query to achieve whole word matching.

```
SELECT  source, target
    FROM  tm
    WHERE  source REGEXP '\\bword\\b'
      AND  customer = 'COMPANY X'
      AND  language = 'YYY'
    ORDER BY  CHAR_LENGTH(source)
    LIMIT  5;
```

There are 2 customers and 2 languages currently.

My goal is to find the top 5 closest matches of a phrase among hundreds of thousands of English sentences. The reason the fetched records are ordered by `CHAR_LENGTH` is because the shorter the length, the higher the match ratio, since `REGEXP '\\bword\\b'` makes sure `source` has `word` already.

The tm table:

```
CREATE TABLE tm(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    source TEXT(7000) NOT NULL,
    target TEXT(6000) NOT NULL,
    language CHAR(3),
    customer VARCHAR(10),
    INDEX src_cus_lang (source(755), customer, language)
```

The query above took about 4.5 seconds to finish, which is very slow for me and my PC that has an Intel Core i5-10400F, 16GB RAM and an SSD.

The EXPLAIN command showed the below result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1117154
     filtered: 1.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to delelte the `src_cus_lang` index and created a new one `(customer, language, source(755))`, but no improvement at all.

I can think of a few solutions:

1. Recreate the `tm` table, ordering by CHAR_LENGTH(source) in the process. This is not ideal for me as I'd like to keep the original order of the table.
2. Create a new column named `src_len`, i.e. the length of the source. However, `ORDER BY src_len` is still very slow.
3. Split the `tm` table into 4 separate ones by `customer` and `language`. Not ideal for me.
4. Index the `source` column. Still very slow.
5. Use `INDEX(customer, language)`. Took 1.4 seconds longer for both normal words and special words like '.vnet'.

Is there a way to cut the execution time down to less than 0.5 seconds?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Is src_cus_lang the only secondary index? I'd try (Customer, language, source).

Comment: @Jarlh I use MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh Already tried that, with src_cus_lang deleted. Still slow.

Comment: Do you have fresh statistics? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Try changing the order of the index to customer, language, source

Comment: The image of EXPLAIN is useless, as it is unreadable. Please post the text version instead.

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT ... \G`  turns it vertical.

Comment: @Ken White @ Rick James I added the `EXPLAIN SELECT ... \G` output. Please see above.

Comment: @slaakso Already tried that, with src_cus_lang deleted. Still slow. I forgot to mentioned this. Added to post now.

Comment: Using `WHERE  source REGEXP '\\bword\\b'` removes the ability to use any index except a full-text index, because it requires running the regex on every single row and evaluate it looking for matches. You need a full-text index and should remove the useless existing `src_cus_lang` index, which is expensive to maintain but useless to use at all unless you're doing matches for content at the very beginning of source (e.g., `WHERE source LIKE 'Smit%'`).

Comment: @Ken White I get an error message `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'tm.PRIMARY'`, which is confusing to me, because `id` is the PRIMARY key and shouldn't have duplicates.

Comment: What in the world does that have to do with the issues we've been discussing here? You're asking me about some other totally unrelated issue. Click the Ask Question button and ask about it there, as it has nothing to do with the performance issue you asked about here.

Comment: @Ken White I forgot to mention the error message was thrown when creating the FULLTEXT index, and should have asked that question in a new post.

Comment: @wbzy00 That error is a bug with MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197185/12013462

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially useless:

```
INDEX src_cus_lang (source(755), customer, language)
```

The prefixing keeps the rest of the columns from being very useful.  `REGEXP` requires checking all 1.1M rows.

This would be better:

```
INDEX(customer, language)
```

It will at least filter on those two columns, then apply the `REGEXP` fewer times.

Since it usually wants to finish with the `WHERE` before considering the `ORDER BY`, your attempts at src_len, etc, did not help.

If there are only 4 different combinations of `customer` and `language`, not much can be done.

However, you should consider a `FULLTEXT(source)` index.  With such,

```
MATCH(source) AGAINST('+word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND ...
```

will work much faster.

Also try `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`.

Comment: I will use `MATCH... AGAINST...` later in order to implement the fuzzy matching feature. I still need whole word match though, in order to implement cocordance searching, i.e. finding sentences by a whole phrase.

Comment: I just tried the `INDEX(customer, language)` and deleted the src_cus_lang index. The query time is now 3 seconds.

Comment: @wbzy00 - `FULLTEXT` is not for "fuzzy", it is for "words".  True, it is not "exact" words, but words plus different endings (singular/plural/etc).

Comment: `INDEX(customer, language)` actually increased the query time. With this index, the query time is 3 seconds, but the original query time is actually 1.78 seconds, not 4.5 seconds. Please check the updated post above.

Comment: "2 customers and 2 languages"; hence my index was not selective enough.

Comment: Full text search is a beast! Took only 0.06 seconds. What's more, it can find fuzzy matched sentences and return the most relevant results first when using `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`. I wish I had knew about it earlier.

Comment: It seems FTS doesn't support word stemming or morphology. By "words plus different endings (singular/plural/etc)", do you mean using wild card characters in boolean mode (`developer*` for example)?

Comment: Try it with your data.